# Intellij Idea - Java program doesn't work properly after building jar

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I have a weird problem with java - I am programming in Intellij Idea, I am using this little code to make basic authorization to site

```
        String authString = name + ":" + password;
        byte[] binaryData = authString.getBytes();
        String authStringEnc = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(binaryData));
        URL url = new URL(webPage);
        URLConnection urlConnection = url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Basic " + authStringEnc);
        InputStream is_auth = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is_auth);
```

This code worked for some weeks, but I continued writing my program. Then yesterday I saw that - program works when I click run in Intellij, but when I start a .jar file, this line cannot be done:

```
        String authStringEnc = new String(Base64.encodeBase64(binaryData));
```

I don't know why, but program stops when doing this line. But when I click run or debug in Intellij, everything is working.

Btw. I am using this library for encodeBase64:

```
        import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
```

If you don't know why it isn't working, maybe you can share with me idea to make a basic authorization to site. Thanks in advance.

Comment: In my opinion, handling authentication and authorization manually is usually not a very good idea. Using a framework, like spring security, will be a lot easier and give you a battle-hardened solution.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the [Apache Commons Codec jar](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-codec/commons-codec) to your [classpath when you run the jar file](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html). You should make sure that any other jar files/libraries that you have added in IntelliJ are also on the classpath.

Comment: Probably your point, but how could I add jar to my classpath?
In Intellij, I used Project Structure-> Modules->Dependeces->added external library containing this file, but still It doesn't work after I start program by jar file instead of running in intellij

Is there any way I could use external library, in my program without sharing this library? I mean I only want 1 jar file with program

Comment: My second link shows you how to do this - you need to run the jar from the command line, you can't simply double-click on it

Answer (score 0):

You should use logging in order to research your stacktrace. Probably you have some ClassNotFound exception or something similarly obvious.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is:
I only had to refresh jar artifact. I deleted old artifact and created it again, after this everything is working well.